# Opening image in new tab

Tags: html, image

I am trying to open an image in a new tab in the browser when I click on an  element. The image is in the public folder in images. When I click on the  element a new tab opens, but it says page not found. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do it. I am using node JS and express.

```
<a class="btn1" href="http:localhost:3000/images/Logo.png" target="_blank">Display Info</a>
```

Comment: please add full code

Comment: This question requires a bit of research. You have to write the routes for accessing the image.

Comment: I was trying the info from this link:

Comment: https://codelikeadev.com/blog/open-image-in-new-tab-html

Comment: You might want to check the structure of the directory where the current page is present and that of the image

Comment: When I copy the http:localhost:3000/images/Logo.png and paste in my browser then the image is displayed.

Comment: remove http:localhost:3000 from the href. keep it like `href='/images/Logo.png'`